# ChangeEvent blocks QMDISubWIndow

Tags: qt

n my App I use a QMDIArea. In this I open now a subclassed MDIChild that has a master class. Inside the master class I set the virtual changeEvent of the subwindow. But if I use this event I cannot move the window in the QMDIArea anymore and the sub window is not create in maximized.
If I remove the Event from the class it works again well. Do I use the Event the wrong way?

MdiChildBase.h

```
private:
    virtual void changeEvent(QEvent * e);
```

MdiChildBase.cpp

```
void MdiChildBase::changeEvent(QEvent * e) {

    if(e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange && this->isActiveWindow()) {
       // .. this is now the active window
        qDebug("Iam active now");
    }
    QWidget::changeEvent(e);

}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc Why this question was closed? It is no duplicate it has a complete different question.  Two problems with the same line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reading the docs and try something around the solution for this question is:

```
void MdiChildBase::changeEvent(QEvent * e) {

    QMdiSubWindow::changeEvent(e);
    if(e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange && this->isActiveWindow()) {
       // .. this is now the active window
        qDebug("Iam active now");
    }

}
```